# isomorphic when base changed to stalks means locally isomorphic?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I came across with the following problem:

If $f : X \rightarrow Y$ is a morphism of finite type over an affine scheme of a Noetherian ring $Y = \operatorname{Spec} A$ such that the base change $f' : X \times_Y \operatorname{Spec} \mathcal{O}_{Y,y} \rightarrow \operatorname{Spec} \mathcal{O}_{Y,y}$ is an isomorphism, then there exists an open neighborhood $V$ of y with $f^{-1}(V) → V$ an isomorphism?

This problem occurs when I followed the proof of Qing Liu's book, Proposition 4.4.2.
If $X = \operatorname{Spec} B$ is also affine then I have a solution, but I don't know how to use this affine case for the general case.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you come across any thoughts of your own? This should be pretty straightforwards: finite morphisms are affine, so $X$ is affine too, then you can just play with rings.

Comment: Sorry, this is typo, I meant 'of finite type.'

Comment: Still, the question of what you've come up with so far is relevant. Without some indication of your thoughts on this problem or why this problem is relevant, you will be unlikely to receive much help.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I added some information.

Comment: Per your thoughts: you should use the definition of "finite type" to try to reduce to the case that $X$ is affine, or find an obstruction to doing so.

Comment: By definition of morphisms of finite type $X$ is covered by finitely many affine open subsets $\operatorname{Spec} B_i$, but to show the problem by taking $V$ to be the distinguished open subset of $Y$, $f^{-1}(V)$ must also be affine. However, I don't see how to take such a V. This is where I stuck.